# How do you get flutter web pages to show up on search engines such as Google, Edge & Firefox?

Tags: flutter-web

I understand that flutter is still in it's development stages but I really enjoy building apps using the dart language.

Would it be possible to programatically create individual html files which holds all the basic metadata and SEO code needed to show up on a search engine?

Answer (score 2):

[You can add SEO META tags but they will be the same for the whole single page app because Flutter Web's navigation is based on hashes - bad for crawlers trying to index your site.](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-Flutter-web-good-with-SEO)

Flutter is more optimized for single page web applications.

You can try `angular dart`, it seems to be better optimized for SEO for some reason.